# Convert csv to xlsx with ';' delimiter

Tags: powershell, csv, xlsx, powershell-5.0

I need transform my csv file to xlsx file using Excel module in powershell 5. That i already try, and code below work but it very very slow (4000rows in csv take about 3 hours). I want to improve my speed but if i use any other variations to send data into `Export-Excel` cmdlet it doesn't work(file created but cannot open). Delimiters in file can be only `';'`

```
somecode......
$out = Import-Csv -Path "D:\psstudio\projects\admins_list.csv" -Header "Имя ПК", "Состав группы локальных администраторов", "Пользователь/Группа", "Доменная/Локальная", "DN" -Delimiter ';' -Encoding Default `
| Convertto-Csv -Delimiter ';' | Convertfrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'

$out | ForEach-Object{ Export-Excel -InputObject $_ -Path "D:\resultlocadm($(get-date -Format d)).xlsx" -AutoSize -TableName "localadmins" -Append }
```

inside file data example:

```
HOLDING-009-157;Стандартные учетные записи;;;CN=HOLDING-009-157,OU=Компьютеры,DC=mydomain,DC=com
SH-TEL-KYIV-P02;ACCESS_DENIED;;;CN=SH-TEL-KYIV-P02,OU=Компьютеры,DC=mydomain,DC=com
TZ-WMS2018-ESB;ACCESS_DENIED;;;CN=TZ-WMS2018-ESB,OU=Компьютеры,DC=mydomain,DC=com
squid-dnepr-01;ACCESS_DENIED;;;CN=squid-dnepr-01,OU=Компьютеры,DC=mydomain,DC=com
SH-TEL-KYIV-P01;ACCESS_DENIED;;;CN=SH-TEL-KYIV-P01,OU=Компьютеры,DC=mydomain,DC=com
MARKET-204-074;Стандартные учетные записи;;;CN=MARKET-204-074,OU=Компьютеры,DC=mydomain,DC=com
MARKET-28-2-101;Стандартные учетные записи;;;CN=MARKET-28-2-101,OU=АП28А,OU=Компьютеры,DC=mydomain,DC=com
MARKET-28-7-038;Стандартные учетные записи;;;CN=MARKET-28-7-038,OU=АП28А,OU=Компьютеры,DC=mydomain,DC=com
MARKET-N-94144;NO_PING;;;CN=MARKET-N-94144,OU=АП28А,OU=Компьютеры,DC=mydomain,DC=com
MARKET-28-6-054;Стандартные учетные записи;;;CN=MARKET-28-6-054,OU=АП28А,OU=Компьютеры,DC=mydomain,DC=com
MARKET-28-6-161;Стандартные учетные записи;;;CN=MARKET-28-6-161,OU=АП28А,OU=Компьютеры,DC=mydomain,DC=com
MARKET-28-6-161;pro;User;WinNT://mydomain/MARKET-28-6-161/pro;CN=MARKET-28-6-161,OU=АП28А,OU=Компьютеры,DC=mydomain,DC=com
MARKET-28-6-022;Стандартные учетные записи;;;CN=MARKET-28-6-022,OU=АП28А,OU=Компьютеры,DC=mydomain,DC=com
MARKET-28-6-022;odenbah;User;WinNT://mydomain/odenbah;CN=MARKET-28-6-022,OU=АП28А,OU=Компьютеры,DC=mydomain,DC=com
```

Answer (score 0):

This is totally fine, I don't see how it can be improved unless you wanna write something in C or C++ to improve it :)

```
$out = Import-Csv -Path "D:\psstudio\projects\admins_list.csv" -Header "Имя ПК", "Состав группы локальных администраторов", "Пользователь/Группа", "Доменная/Локальная", "DN" -Delimiter ';' -Encoding Default
```

This 2 are not doing anyhting: `| Convertto-Csv -Delimiter ';' | Convertfrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'`

Starting from `ImportExcel v7+` (if im not wrong) you can use `-InputObject` like this, which will make things a lot faster:

```
Export-Excel -InputObject $out -Path "D:\resultlocadm($(get-date -Format d)).xlsx" -AutoSize -TableName "localadmins"
```

Edit:

```
PS C:\> $out = Import-Csv -Path "$home\documents\test\input\csv.csv" -Header "Имя ПК", "Состав группы локальных администраторов", "Пользователь/Группа", "Доменная/Локальная", "DN" -Delimiter ';' -Encoding Default

PS C:\> $out|get-random -count 3

Имя ПК                                  : SH-TEL-KYIV-P01
Состав группы локальных администраторов : ACCESS_DENIED
Пользователь/Группа                     : 
Доменная/Локальная                      : 
DN                                      : CN=SH-TEL-KYIV-P01,OU=ÐšÐ¾Ð¼Ð¿ÑŒÑŽÑ‚ÐµÑ€Ñ‹,DC=mydomain,DC=com

Имя ПК                                  : MARKET-28-7-038
Состав группы локальных администраторов : Ð¡Ñ‚Ð°Ð½Ð´Ð°Ñ€Ñ‚Ð½Ñ‹Ðµ ÑƒÑ‡ÐµÑ‚Ð½Ñ‹Ðµ Ð·Ð°Ð¿Ð¸ÑÐ¸
Пользователь/Группа                     : 
Доменная/Локальная                      : 
DN                                      : CN=MARKET-28-7-038,OU=ÐÐŸ28Ð,OU=ÐšÐ¾Ð¼Ð¿ÑŒÑŽÑ‚ÐµÑ€Ñ‹,DC=mydomain,DC=com

Имя ПК                                  : squid-dnepr-01
Состав группы локальных администраторов : ACCESS_DENIED
Пользователь/Группа                     : 
Доменная/Локальная                      : 
DN                                      : CN=squid-dnepr-01,OU=ÐšÐ¾Ð¼Ð¿ÑŒÑŽÑ‚ÐµÑ€Ñ‹,DC=mydomain,DC=com

PS C:\> Import-Module importexcel

PS C:\> Export-Excel -InputObject $out -Path "$home\documents\test\input\test.xlsx" -AutoSize -TableName "localadmins"

PS C:\> ii "$home\documents\test\input\test.xlsx"
```

[image: export-excel result]

Comment: if  i dont use `| Convertto-Csv -Delimiter ';' | Convertfrom-Csv -Delimiter ';' ` then file dont formating properly. And if i use `-InputObject` it's create file that cannot open.

Comment: Checkout my edit, not sure what to tell you, it works fine for me.

Comment: for 20 items it work for me to(open takes about 15-20 seconds). But if use my long method `foreach-object` that 4000 rows open in 5-10 second